# Adding tags in files in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, file-management, tags

Is it possible to add tags in files in Windows 7 so that when I search for a particular tag, I get the file I'm looking for?

I have a lot of .psd files of different businesses in a single folder and I wish to add tags to each files. For example, tags like *flat*, *blue*, *3 columns*, *ecommerce*, etc. So when I use the Windows Explorer's search box, I get the files I'm looking for.

Is there a built-in system for tagging in Windows or do I need to install a software for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The windows explorer allows you to add tags down in the details panel at the bottom of the window. However, it only displays this option for a couple of file types. I was only able to test it for jpeg files here at work. But since .psd is a pretty well known extension you might be lucky...

Answer (score 2):

There is built-tagging in Windows, but as Dunkit pointed out, it's only available for certain file extensions, as Windows knows how to properly embed the tags in those types.

Windows can **not** read or write tags onto a .psd file. I just confirmed that by testing on my system. One viable alternative would be to include the "tag" phrase in the actual filename, and search by that to get your results.

As for third-party software, I'm sure there's some sort of search software for photographers ro designers that tag their work and makes that searchable, but I'm not aware of any offhand.